# In postman tests, How to assert the response parameter which as special chars in it

Tags: postman, newman, postman-pre-request-script

I'm using postman tests section to automate the APIs

If the response parameter is something like this `"currency": "USD",`, then we assert this by `pm.expect(jsonResponse.currency, 'USD');`

But if the response parameter is something like this `"super-card.DCC": "false",`, in which key has `-`, `.(dot)` in it.
Then asserting like this `pm.expect(jsonResponse.postingAttributes.super-card.DCC, false);` is not working.

Its failing with  `ReferenceError: card is not defined`

Here is the screenshot: [image]

Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For JSON properties like these, you need to use [bracket notation](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/65-dot-vs-bracket-notation/) to access the value:

```js
pm.expect(jsonResponse.postingAttributes["super-card.DCC"], false)
```

You're not actually asserting anything here though, as long as the property is in the JSON response structure, it will pass the "test", regardless of the value.

As an example, this endpoint returns the request information and I'm sending a `GET` request here. Adding the same script as you have, you can see this is passing:

[image]

The second argument in the `pm.expect()` function is an optional message that would be shown if the test failed.

[image]

You would need to use:

```js
pm.expect(jsonResponse.postingAttributes["super-card.DCC"]).to.equal("false")
```